# Encode local name like XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName in pure XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, encode, ucs2

Hello I'd like handle Xml-Files which have encoded node names like for example:

```xml
<CST_x002F_SOMETHING>
....
</CST_x002F_SOMETHING>
```

This node name should be decoded to `CST/SOMETHING`.

These node names were encoded for example via [EncodeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename?view=netcore-3.1). Is there any built-in XQuery-function to decode these names? Or do you have an encoding / decoding function?

XML Files produced by Oracle-DB use the same escaping mechanism.

Comment: BTW: I use saxon from saxonica

Comment: Are you using the .NET version of Saxon? Then you could set up an extension function http://saxonica.com/documentation9.9/index.html#!extensibility/integratedfunctions/ext-simple-N to call the EncodeName method you have linked to.

Comment: I switched to the java version because the dotnet version seems to be slower compared to the java version (it is caused by the class loading mechanism of IKVM / Exception handling).
But the Java version could be faster, too. What I mean is especially the start up time. In the debugger I can see most of the time is used to do "JarVerification". I tried to disable it but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fn:analyze-string()` to split the string and match the `_XXXX_` parts. When you encounter one of these parts, use `bin:hex()` to convert hex to binary, then `bin:unpack-unsigned-integer()` to convert the binary to an integer, then `fn:codepoints-to-string()` to convert the integer codepoint to a string.

The binary functions are documented at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/expath-binary

Requires Saxon-PE or higher.

You could also use the new saxon:replace-with() function:

```
declare namespace bin = 'http://expath.org/ns/binary'; 
saxon:replace-with('CST_x002F_SOMETHING', '_x[0-9A-F]{4}_', 
   function($s) {$s => substring(3, 4) 
                    => bin:hex() 
                    => bin:unpack-unsigned-integer(0,2) 
                    => codepoints-to-string()}
```

outputs `CST/SOMETHING`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to do it without such extension-functions like bin:hex()? Currently I have only the HE available...

Comment: Yes, you can do it without extension functions, but you'll have to write a lot more code.

Comment: I did it now with some "preprocess-step" which converted the node names to attributes. There seems to be no easy and cheap solution in XQuery, but thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

> XQuery

```
for $x in doc('input.xml')//CST_x002F_SOMETHING
return rename node $x as "whateveryouneed"
```

Comment: The node names look strange just because they use "not allowed charcters" like "slash" or "blank".
With this encoding Oracle / Microsoft removes this restriction. But I found no implementation in xquery

Comment: if you create a node via element constructor and non-simple characters you get a dynamic error

Comment: I don't know the node names... But I need to look them up without encoding - to compare those strings I need to decode them